# Extracting data and labels from .mat file

Tags: matlab, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I am currently trying to prepare data consisting of images with an attached label, where each image and label is currently stored as a .mat file.

My question is how i can extract the images and labels?

I am currently using scipy.io.loadmat, and i am getting the following result when printing:

```
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Fri Feb 01 22:33:35  2019', '__version__': '1.0', '__globals__': [], 'GTLabel': array([], shape=(0, 1), dtype=object), 'GTMask': array([[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   ...,
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)}
```

But whenever i try to extract the X key by .get('X'), and plot the image, i get the following error:
"Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float"

Or when i try to print the label, i just receive the output "None"

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide the '.mat' file? Sounds like perhaps once the image and tag are being imported and not being interpreted by scipy. What I would check:

1. Check that scipy can interpret images from .mat files in the first place
2. If working in an IDE where you can visually inspect variables, assign the imported file, then take the time to inspect it and make sure the contents are arranged in the way that you (and more importantly, scipy) expect them to be.
3. Depending on how inspection goes, try to parse the file up so it can be interpreted correctly or consider another way of storing the information.

Note that in MatLab color images are handled as an MxNx3 unit8 matrix (one z dimension each for R, G, B levels). I've never exported images from matlab into another program as a '.mat' before, especially with text labels, but hopefully the above train of thought helps narrow things down.